# Bootstrap multi-column carousel smooth scrolling/easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the following multi-item carousel to scroll smoothly to the next item. Right now, it jumps to the next item when clicked, but I would like it to transition/ease - or go smoothly - to the next section.

```
<style>
body {
    width: 1400px;    
}
.Blog {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
}

.inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.Blog-item {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
}

.controlDiv {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.control {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px;
}
</style>

<div class="Blog">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="Blog-item" >
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x356?text=1" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Blog-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x356?text=2" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Blog-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x356?text=3" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Blog-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x356?text=4" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Blog-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x356?text=5" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Blog-item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/727x356?text=6" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controlDiv">
        <a class="control control-left glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left" href=""></a>
        <a class="control control-right glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" href=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.control-right').click(function () {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).parents('.Blog').find('.Blog-item').first().insertAfter($(this).parents('.Blog').find('.Blog-item').last());
        return false;
    });
    $('.control-left').click(function () {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).parents('.Blog').find('.Blog-item').last().insertBefore($(this).parents('.Blog').find('.Blog-item').first());
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bcw8dysawk/z1wo4uy6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you are after something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/uh2skm0e/

I basically used jQuery's `animate` function to animate elements on the page and inserted a modified version of your original code into the `animate`'s callback function.

I completed the 'next slide' operation by modifying the `margin-left`css attribute and the 'previous slide' operation by modifying the `left` css attribute.

You can see both options and pick your preferred method (`left` is generally used).

I also needed to add a `position:relative` to the `.Blog-item` css rule since the script manipulates `z-index` and this requires elements to have an explicit CSS position.

Two things to mention:

1) My solution is a pure JavaScript solution. You can look into using the `transition` CSS attribute to achieve animations without the need for JavaScript, but you may need to reorganise your code slightly (which leads me onto my next point)

2) Usually with sliders, the element positions are not actually changed in the markup...it's only the visibility settings (`display` CSS attribute) that are changed. So when 'slide 2' displays, all slides are set to `display:none` except for 'slide 2'. This means all you need to do is use JavaScript to add a class to the visible slide and it will display...couple this with the `transition` CSS attribute and you can easily achieve some good effects.

Let me know if this is what you were after.

Comment: Alvin, thank you so much. I just saw this and it looks like exactly what I was looking for! I am going to take a closer look now and get back to the thread. I really appreciate all the comments as well, as they will make a huge difference.

Comment: Alvin ... This worked perfectly for me, and it was relatively easy to tweak (just for experimentation) and implement. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brian - No problem, I'm glad it helped...yeah, comments always make a massive difference.